# Xcode ToolChain version

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

I recently realized in the terminal that my swift version  was swift 3.0 (swift-3.0-GM-CANDIDATE). I have already updated to xcode 8.3 and I know xcode 8.3 comes with swift 3.1, so I checked the xcode toolchain set in xcode preference pane and it was set to xcode 8.3, but when i opened the directory containing the toolchains i found out that the latest xcode toolchain file was just a alias that points back to the swift-3.0-GM-CANDIDATE.xtoolchain. What do I do, do i download the standalone xcode 8.3 toolchain and install?

Comment: The Xcode 8.3 toolchain is not in /Library/Developer/Toolchains but somewhere in the Xcode bundle. What does "swift -version" show?

Comment: swift -version shows "Apple Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-GM-CANDIDATE)"

Comment: What does `xcode-select -p` show?

Comment: this is what it shows : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer